# phpunit selenium select with assign value

Tags: selenium, phpunit

When i assign the value it is not work

```
var $title = "name=order[contact][title]" ;
var $title_val = "label=Mr" ;

public function fillCustomerInfo() {
        $this->select($this->title, $title_val);        
        return $this;
}
```

Normal is working

```
public function fillCustomerInfo() {
    $this->select("name=order[contact][title]","label=Mr");         
    return $this;
```

}

So,How can i assign the value in the function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

var $title_val = "label=Mr" ;

if you call the variable you need to use $this->title_val;

So.The Correct code is

```
var $title = "name=order[contact][title]" ;
var $title_val = "label=Mr" ;

public function fillCustomerInfo() {
        $this->select($this->title, $this->title_val);        
        return $this;
}
```